# R - How to reshape a dataframe based on the relationship between two columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe, `df`:

```
ICD    MRN      Adm        
 X     24     1/01/2015      
 Y     21     1/22/2015      
 A     10     2/09/2015      
 B     10     2/09/2015      
 C     10     2/09/2015      
 F     97     4/10/2015      
 X     97     4/10/2015      
 Z     33     5/17/2015
```

What I would like to do is have ICD values go into their own column for each MRN.  It's ok if an MRN only has one ICD associated with it, but if there are multiple values they should go into their own column.

Something like this:

```
MRN       ICD.1      ICD.2    ICD.3     Adm    
24         X          NA       NA       1/01/2015
21         Y          NA       NA       1/22/2015
10         A          B        C        2/09/2015
97         F          X        NA       4/10/2015
33         Z          NA       NA       5/17/2015
```

I cannot figure out how to do this!  It is hard for me to even ask the question!  I suspect it requires usage of `reshape2`, but I am weak in that area and would love some help from the community.

Comment: Yup, that would be the `dcast` function from `reshape2`

Comment: If it is possible, would you be willing to show me how that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way - duplicate somewhere...

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(MRN) %>%
  mutate(ICD_lbl = paste0("ICD.", data.table::rleid(ICD))) %>%
  spread(ICD_lbl, ICD)
```

Comment: This does work, but I would like to see an example with `dcast` and `reshape2`.  If no one posts that I'll mark this as the correct answer.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I don't think you need rleid here. Anyways, the data.table analogue is `dcast(setDT(DF), MRN + Adm ~ rowid(MRN), value.var="ICD")`. Feel free to add it.

Comment: I think the rleid can be replaced with `row_number(ICD)`, but I'm not sure so won't make the edit.